# How to change the values of a nested array to all same string?

Tags: javascript

I would like to change a nested array that contains a * to all the same * values . For instance, this grid

```
  ["A", "*", "C"],
  ["D", "E", "p"],
  ["G", "H", "I"],
```

Would turn into

```
  ["*", "*", "*"],
  ["D", "E", "p"],
  ["G", "H", "I"],
```

Here is my function so far:

```
function changeArr(grid) {
    for (let arr of grid) {
        if (arr.includes("*")) {
            arr.forEach(element => element = "*")
        }
    }
    return grid;
}
```

My function just returns the same initial grid that was passed through the function. I've also tried

```
function changeArr(grid) {
    for (let arr of grid) {
        if (arr.includes("*")) {
            arr.splice(0, 3, ["*","*","*"])
        }
    }
    return grid;
}
```

But this creates a nested array within a nested array! I feel like this can be easily accomplished with a forEach but not sure how.

Comment: While it's not an extremely nice code, your attempt with `splice()` should work after you remove the brackets, so `arr.splice(0, 3, "*", "*", "*");` remains.

Comment: Thank you! Should've realized that was a simple fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `forEach`, you are not really modifying the array. You are passing a value to `forEach`, corresponding to the values of the nested array. So when you change element's variable value, you are just changing it inside the `forEach` callback.

There are a few ways to do this... you can go something like this.

```js
    let array = [
        ['A', '*', 'C'],
        ['A', 'B', 'C']
    ]
    
    for (let nestedArray of array) {
        if (nestedArray.includes('*')) {
            for (let i = 0; i < nestedArray.length; i++) nestedArray[i] = '*';
        }
    }
    
    console.log(array);
```

Or go by using splice if they all have the same fixed size (or even reassign the nestedArray to a `['*', '*', '*']`).

Just to be clear: If you have this array:
`['a', 'b', 'c']`

And iterate it with `forEach`:

array.forEach(element => ...)

`element` will have the values 'a', 'b', 'c'. But those are NOT the same 'a', 'b', 'c' of the array. They are copies. So reassigning `element` to another value, won't affect the original array.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, a function that iterates through the array and find the nested array which contains * and then replace its values

```js
var grid = [
  ['A', '*', 'B'],
  ['C', 'D', 'E'],
  ['H', 'G', 'F']
]

function changeArr(grid) {
  grid.forEach(arr => {
    if (arr.includes('*')) {
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr.splice(i, i, '*');
      }
    }
  })
}

console.log(grid);
changeArr(grid);
console.log(grid);
```